# How to get all a tag innerHTML in a span class

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
<span class="mgen">
<a rel="tag">Action</a> 
<a rel="tag">Adventure</a> 
<a rel="tag">Apocalypse</a> 
<a rel="tag">Fantasy</a> 
<a rel="tag">Magic</a> 
</span>
```

How do I get all the a tag inner html like

> Action Adventure Apocalypse Fantsay Magic

I tried using `document.querySelector(".mgen a").innerHTML`, but I am only getting first a tag innerHTML. I don't want to use loop to get all innerHTML as it would be lengthy.

Comment: You can use querySelectorAll to get all the elements but then you’ll have to iterate on it to find the textContent of each one of them z

Comment: @ABGR yeah that's a drag so I am here to get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try getting the `textContent` of the `.mgen` element. This would return only the text content of the inner elements.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".mgen").textContent)
```

```html
<span class="mgen">
<a rel="tag">Action</a> 
<a rel="tag">Adventure</a> 
<a rel="tag">Apocalypse</a> 
<a rel="tag">Fantasy</a> 
<a rel="tag">Magic</a> 
</span>
```

If you want it in the same line with only one space between the words, we can remove the `newline` and other spacing using regex and replace them with `space`

```
console.log(document.querySelector(".mgen").textContent.replace(/\s/g, ' '))
```

Comment: Why did we getting innerHTML from main class rather then a tag which is inside of class mgen can you tell me logic behind it?

Comment: If we get the innerHTML from the `tag` we would need to loop over each one of them, or we might get only the first one. Since `mgen` is the parent of all the `tags` we use its content and then clean up the text as required.

Comment: Thanks for explaining I understood it I was thinking textContent and innerHTML works the same, I was wrong thanks again

Comment: No problem, `innerHTML` always gives you the raw HTML content. On the other hand, `textContent` gives you only the text found inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.innerText` property on the targeted element. `.innerText()` represents the rendered text content of a node and its descendants.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <span class="mgen">
        <a rel="tag">Action</a>
        <a rel="tag">Adventure</a>
        <a rel="tag">Apocalypse</a>
        <a rel="tag">Fantasy</a>
        <a rel="tag">Magic</a>
    </span>
    <script>
        let element = document.querySelector(".mgen")
        console.log(element.innerText)
    </script>
</body>
```

You can also use `textContent` property. They work similar with few [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext).

Comment: Why does document.querySelector(".mgen a").innerHTML not work?

Comment: Because `.mgen a` selects the first `a` tag only.